# Android trouble with fetching contacts from the Phone-Book

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts

In my application, I am trying to send SMS,but what I want is when I fetch the contacts from the phone-book for adding recipients, I want all the numbers of that particular contact will appear, and i will choose one of them to send the SMS .Lets say I want to select "XYZ" contact from the phone-book. When I click on "XYZ", a screen will appear to ask, which contact number u want to select(if this contact have some multi-numbers saved otherwise just select this contact simply and display it to the edit-text view).
I have no idea what to do for this .
If any body  know , please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this thread and download the sample and work on it

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html

check this thread too.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/

Comment: is it possible ?? what i am trying ?

Comment: check the above two sample